# Genymotion increase internal storage space

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, genymotion

I'm running out of internal storage space on my Genymotion emulator.
[image]

Strange thing is when looking at properties of this emulator in virtual box I see that it has 16gb external memory.

[image]
 How can I increase the storage size so that I can install more apps without deleting existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, you can increase internal space. But it much more complicated than just resize virtual disk of your VM.

First of all, you increase the size of `android_data_disk.vmdk`. Here you need copying it several times to convert to vdi format (only vdi size can be changed) and vice versa to get large enough vmdk disk.

After that, you should use another VM to get access to a filesystem on vmdk and resize it. The easiest way is using Ubuntu.

Finally, you can replace `android_data_disk.vmdk` in your Android VM onto one which you resize.

I am the author of the original tutorial on the Reddit. Full tutorial too long to be placed here, because it contains a lot of screenshots. I leave the link onto this tutorial. [Genymotion increase internal storage space](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/bj7ezk/genymotion_increase_internal_storage_space/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)